# Vue.js list rendering diff: "same object" vs "has same values"

Tags: vue.js, key, diff, v-for

I have just hit a reactivity problem in Vue.js (2.6.12) component. It was not re-computing and re-rendering after its props were updated. The issue is that the component is used in a list with `v-for` with a `key`. The `key` was not changing, but the object's data was changing i.e. it was the same object, but its data was different.

The `key` is used as an optimization for diffing the list in `v-for` so it can re-use and re-order the same components without re-creating them. My original `key` was the object's id and the solution is to create the `key` from the id and all the object's changing data. That leads to other issues, like losing the component's internal data state, which has no need to be stored in a Vuex store.

My question is, is there a way in Vue.js (maybe in v3?) to tell in `v-for` not only if the object is the same (via `key` using object's id) but also if the object has the same data? Which will update the prop and re-computed and re-render the component without losing its internal data?

Funny thing is that the component's props are updating, it just does not re-compute and re-render. Verified via the Vue Devtools in a browser.

**EDIT:**

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6zx9Lr/) where the reactivity does not work. It is using a Vuex store and the array for `v-for` is a computed property, which joins two properties from the store.

I just figured out that the problem is the joining of the values via the `map` on line `67: o.number = extras[o.id]`. After replacing this with `Vue.set(o, 'number', extras[o.id])` it is working!

Comment: It's best to give a simplified code example reproducing the problem to let others see exactly how you've used the props and so on.  Because there is no such reactivity problem described above when everything is done properly.  A small example:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/04s1jt8g/

Comment: @Dan I am amazed that it is working. I even modified that fiddle with a prop of type `Object` with default value and bind the whole object, instead of just its value i.e. `<comp v-for="obj in objs" :key="obj.id" :value="obj"></comp>`, and it is still working. Maybe this has something to do with Vuex store? My issue is that Vue Devtools shows that the props have changed, but computed properties are not re-computed and the component is not re-drawn. I will try to make a minimal demo with Vuex.

Comment: This reactivity is the primary feature of Vue so it better work.  If I had to guess, you're encountering the object [change detection caveat](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) and need to use `Vue.set`.  For example, when dynamically creating a Vuex state item.  Notice in my example that all data properties exist beforehand so it doesn't have that issue

Comment: @Dan you were right with the `Vue.set`! And I have thought that it bit me so many times that I knew what I was doing :D Here it was a bit more complicated because the array for `v-for` is a computed property joining two properties from Vuex store and even in the `map` I had to use `Vue.set`. Check the example I have added to my question, please. Can you comment on why the `Vue.set` is also needed in this case? Thank you.

Comment: It's because your computed creates a new property (`number`) on each Vuex `obj` that's not defined in Vuex at the time you set `objs`.  If you had initialized the `objs` to have a `number` property as well, you wouldn't need `Vue.set`.  Another way to prove it is to set `o.text` instead of `o.number` and you'll see it's reactive without `Vue.set`.  Btw, it makes more sense to do this computation in a Vuex getter instead of a computed; getters are computeds for Vuex.  It's nice to decouple the logic from the component, and imagine you needed the result in multiple components

Comment: @Dan thank you for clarification, makes sense now. The fiddle is just a minimal code that reproduces my bug, my real code hides the merging behind a getter.

Comment: No problem, I added everything as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem doesn't exist as described.  Here is a small example of object reactivity working properly:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/04s1jt8g

I'm guessing, however, that you're encountering the [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) and need to use `Vue.set`.

The reason is now clear with the code example:  Your computed creates a new property (`number`) on each Vuex `obj` that's not defined in Vuex at the time you set `objs`. If you had initialized the `objs` to have a `number` property as well, you wouldn't need `Vue.set`. Another way to prove it is to set `o.text` instead of `o.number` and you'll see it's reactive without `Vue.set`

(Btw, it makes more sense to do this computation in a Vuex getter instead of a computed; getters are computeds for Vuex. It's nice to decouple the logic from the component, and imagine you needed the result in multiple components)

Comment: There is one last issue with the `Vue.set` and that is it is modifying the object outside a Vuex store's mutation. That is solved by making an object's copy via `Object.assign(...)` in the `map`.

Comment: True and that would bypass the whole reactivity issue.  You wouldn't need `Vue.set` and your data could leave `number` uninitialized